# Must unplug and replug in USB NIC before it will work

Tags: macbook-pro, network, usb

Relatively new to the world of Mac (few months now) and have a Cable Matters USB wired NIC. WiFi on the mac turned off during all of this.

If I reboot my mac with the USB device inserted (and cable) connected, I have no internet connection and must unplug and re-plug in the device, then all works well.

Hanging off my other USB port is a powered USB hub 7 ports, 5 used.  Has anyone heard of this happening before with other peripherals?  Thanks.